# Postgres user without password

Tags: postgresql, password

I'm creating unit tests on a python application that uses digital certs on the server. Since I am not testing the connection between the server and the database, I need to setup the temporary test database to authenticate w/o a password for the CN listed in the certificate. The production server uses peer authentication, but I want to avoid having to force the unit test to run under a different username.

Long story short, is there a way to create a superuser in postgresql with no password in order to create a database, run a schema, etc.?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by putting a line in `pg_hba.conf` that defines a `trust` connection for that user. That line should be *before* the lines defining the peer authentication in order to have a higher priority